# How to change menu text

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, windows-ce

I am currently trying to make our Windows CE device multi language.

To do this I substituted numbers for text in the menu resource like "51234". On Creating the Menu Bar I iterate over the menu and sub menus and convert the textual number to an integer and look it up in a database and convert the text.

```
IDMB_BULK_AUDIT MENU 
BEGIN
    POPUP "51420"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "51432",                 ID_OPTIONS_PREFERENCES
        MENUITEM "51435",                 ID_OPTIONS_STATS
    END
END
```

To get the integer text I am using GetMenuItemInfo and to set the text with SetMenuItemInfo. Sample code is below. I have my own OutputDebug(...) method and this method is called NavigateMenu and is called recursively (refer end if block).

So my question is can I change the menu this way or do I need to build it dynamically (at run time). The code navigates the menu hierarchy and gets the integer values out the calls to GetMenuItemInfo and SetMenuItemInfo all succeed. The CommandBar_DrawMenuBar fails with Invalid Menu Handle (1401).

```
   // This is how I call the method.
   NavigateMenu( pCommandBar->GetMenu( ) );
   if( ::CommandBar_DrawMenuBar( pCommandBar->m_hCommandBar, MenuId ) )
   {
      OutputDebug( L"Draw - OK\n" );
   }
   else
   {
      DWORD lastError = GetLastError( );
      OutputDebug( L"Draw - Fail [%d]\n", lastError );
   }


void CMainFrame::NavigateMenu( HMENU HandleMenu )
{
   wchar_t menuText[ 200 ];

   BOOL cont = TRUE;

   for( int i = 0; cont; ++i )
   {
      MENUITEMINFO menuiteminfo;
      menuiteminfo.cbSize = sizeof( MENUITEMINFO );
      menuiteminfo.fMask = MIIM_SUBMENU | MIIM_TYPE;

      menuiteminfo.dwTypeData = menuText;
      menuiteminfo.cch = 200;
      menuiteminfo.hSubMenu = 0;
      menuiteminfo.fType = MFT_STRING;

      cont = GetMenuItemInfo( HandleMenu, i, true, &menuiteminfo );
      if( cont )
      {
         CStringW menuText2( ( wchar_t * )menuiteminfo.dwTypeData );
         if( menuText2.GetLength( ) )
         {
            const int menuId = StringToInt( menuText2 );
            if( menuId > 0 )
            {
               CStringW menuText3( LoadResString( menuId ) );
               wcscpy( menuText, menuText3 );
               menuiteminfo.cch = menuText3.GetLength( ) + 1;
               menuiteminfo.fMask = MIIM_TYPE;

               //if( ModifyMenu( HandleMenu, i, MF_BYPOSITION, MF_STRING, menuText ) )
               //if( ModifyMenu( HandleMenu, menuiteminfo.wID, MF_BYCOMMAND, MF_STRING, menuText ) )
               if( SetMenuItemInfo( HandleMenu, i, true, &menuiteminfo ) )
               {
               //if( SetMenuItemInfo( HandleMenu, menuiteminfo.wID, false, &menuiteminfo ) )
                  OutputDebug( L"Success - > %d to '%s'\n", menuId, menuiteminfo.dwTypeData );
               }
               else
               {
                  DWORD menuError = GetLastError( );
                  OutputDebug( L"Fail [%d] - > %d to '%s'\n", menuError, menuId, menuiteminfo.dwTypeData );
               }
            }
         }
         if( menuiteminfo.hSubMenu )
         {
            NavigateMenu( menuiteminfo.hSubMenu );
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: [Using the MUI with Applications (Windows CE 5.0)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms904384.aspx).

Comment: What I needed was "HMENU hmenu = SHGetMenu( pCommandBar->m_hWnd );" and use the HMENU from this command and the popup menu text is now modified as I require. The only issue left is the CommandBar button that the menu comes off does not change from its integer value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed was

```
HMENU hmenu = SHGetMenu( pCommandBar->m_hWnd );
NavigateMenu( hmenu );
```

and use the HMENU from this command and the popup menu text is now modified as I require.

To set the toolbar button text i needed to use TB_SETBUTTONINFO on the pCommandBar->m_hWnd;

```
TBBUTTONINFO buttonInfo;
ZeroMemory( &buttonInfo, sizeof( TBBUTTONINFO ) );
buttonInfo.cbSize = sizeof( TBBUTTONINFO );
buttonInfo.dwMask = TBIF_TEXT | TBIF_BYINDEX;// | TBIF_COMMAND ;
wchar_t buffer[200];
buttonInfo.pszText = buffer;
buttonInfo.cchText = 200;
HWND hwnd = pCommandBar->m_hWnd;
::SendMessage( hwnd, TB_GETBUTTONINFO, 0, (LPARAM)&buttonInfo );
OutputDebug( L" *** Button Text = [%s]", buttonInfo.pszText );

buttonInfo.pszText = L"BLAH";
buttonInfo.cchText = 5;

::SendMessage( hwnd, TB_SETBUTTONINFO, 0, (LPARAM)&buttonInfo );
```